# Dealing with missing data using standard ML techniques

Tags: missing-data, data-preprocessing

Why do we have separate techniques like Miss Forest, Miceforest to deal with missing data? Why can't we simply apply standard ML techniques to predict missing values in any column of interest?

Comment: This kind of question is more suitable for [stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com)